# Should we use a local account or Windows account on a Windows8 PC?

Tags: windows-8

I just guided my mum on setting up a Windows account so she can use the W8 Mail app. My understanding is you also have to have this to use the Store.

Now when she turns it on, she is asked for her password. I'm confused, should I have left her using a local account but created a Windows one separately? Does a Windows account mean she will have to be on the internet to login?

Comment: No, you can log in to non-local accounts offline.

Comment: **Only you can decide what is best for your situation.**

Comment: @Ramhound since I don't know the options that is no help at all.

Comment: @John - There are only two options.  A local account that isn't connected to a Microsoft Account and a local account that is connected to a Microsoft Account.  **Only you can decided if connecting a local account to a Microsoft Account is good for you.**

Comment: Why does she have to enter her password now - that is the main issue really?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/disable-remove-password suggests you have to login securely if you use a Windows account. It also suggests you cannot use the Store if you use a local account - is that true? Seems weird, I don't have to login to my iPad I just give my password when I want to buy something.

Comment: I think its more a mentality from Microsoft that a PC is more likely to be a shared machine than an iPad for example; therefore any applications from store (purchases or free) are user specific and that being the case should be attached to user account which then raises security concerns so passwords are required...

Comment: Does a Windows account mean she will have to be on the internet to login? To answer this it doesn't after the first login, Windows will save the credentials locally so it can logged in too either online or offline...